# Integração Sonar + Maven + Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Bom dia a todos, pessoal estou configurando um servidor de integração usando Jenkins + Maven + Sonar Quebe, mas estou com o seguinte cenário: 
1 - Se os testes do jUnit falham o maven interrompe o deploy da aplicação. Blz esse é o resultado esperado.
2 - Se o sonar aponta problemas em meu código(bug) o maven não para e faz o deploy normalmente.

Minha dúvida é se tem como fazer com que o Maven não faça o deploy quando o sonar indicar um bug ou até se possível um número máximo de bugs

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas opções para você utilizar depedendo da sua versão do Jenkins, para versões mais antigas essa funcionalidade de checagem dos Quality Gates era feita manualmente através de scripts.

### 1. Quality Gate Plugin

Uma simples integração através [deste plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Quality+Gates+Plugin), você pode configurá-lo em poucos passos conforme mostra a [documentação oficial](https://plugins.jenkins.io/quality-gates)

### 2. Webhooks

A partir da versão 6.2 do Sonar essa checagem pode ser feita por meio de webhooks, conforme mostra [este artigo](https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/)

### 3. Shell Script

Conforme apontado por [ansolsi zied nesta thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873434/how-can-you-make-sonarqube-version-5-2-fail-a-jenkins-build), você pode verificar utilizando o script abaixo:

```
if [ "\`curl -sL -w %{http_code} http://sonar_host/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=project_key -o /dev/null -S --quiet 2>&1 | jsawk -a 'return this.status'\`" == "ERROR" ]; 
then 
  exit 1; 
fi;
```

Substituindo `project_key` pela key do seu projeto cadastrado no Sonar

---

Nas versões anteriores do Sonar, havia um plugin chamado [Build Breaker Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Build+Breaker+Plugin), ele foi descontinuado e aqui você pode ler um [artigo do Sonar](https://blog.sonarsource.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/) explicando porque ele não deve mais ser utilizado.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente usando o Quality Gate Plugin